# Is there any Play Core Library available for Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play-core

Below is the link to Android Library
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore

Comment: I don't think so because this is a benefit of Android as a platform and not iOS you can find the On Demand options of iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/index.html

I highly doubt you will have an alternative in the near future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use in app reviews inside Flutter you can use this package
https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_review

[image: In app review for Flutter]